# Bash sub script redirects input to /dev/null mistakenly

Tags: bash, stdin, file-descriptor, stderr, io-redirection

I'm working on a script to automate the creation of a `.gitconfig` file.

This is my main script that calls a function which in turn execute another file.

**dotfile.sh**

```
COMMAND_NAME=$1
shift
ARG_NAME=$@

set +a

fail() {
  echo "";
  printf "\r[${RED}FAIL${RESET}] $1\n";
  echo "";
  exit 1;
}

set -a

sub_setup() {
  info "This may overwrite existing files in your computer. Are you sure? (y/n)";
  read -p "" -n 1;
    echo "";
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    for ARG in $ARG_NAME; do
      local SCRIPT="~/dotfiles/setup/${ARG}.sh";
      [ -f "$SCRIPT" ] && echo "Applying '$ARG'" && . "$SCRIPT" || fail "Unable to find script '$ARG'";
    done;
  fi;
}

case $COMMAND_NAME in
  "" | "-h" | "--help")
    sub_help;
    ;;
  *)
    CMD=${COMMAND_NAME/*-/}
    sub_${CMD} $ARG_NAME 2> /dev/null;
    if [ $? = 127 ]; then
      fail "'$CMD' is not a known command or has errors.";
    fi;
    ;;
esac;
```

**git.sh**

```
git_config() {
  if [ ! -f "~/dotfiles/git/gitconfig_template" ]; then
    fail "No gitconfig_template file found in ~/dotfiles/git/";
  elif [ -f "~/dotfiles/.gitconfig" ]; then
    fail ".gitconfig already exists. Delete the file and retry.";
  else
    echo "Setting up .gitconfig";

    GIT_CREDENTIAL="cache"

    [ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ] && GIT_CREDENTIAL="osxkeychain";

    user " - What is your GitHub author name?";
    read -e GIT_AUTHORNAME;
    user " - What is your GitHub author email?";
    read -e GIT_AUTHOREMAIL;
    user " - What is your GitHub username?";
    read -e GIT_USERNAME;

    if sed -e "s/AUTHORNAME/$GIT_AUTHORNAME/g" \
    -e "s/AUTHOREMAIL/$GIT_AUTHOREMAIL/g" \
    -e "s/USERNAME/$GIT_USERNAME/g" \
    -e "s/GIT_CREDENTIAL_HELPER/$GIT_CREDENTIAL/g" \
    "~/dotfiles/git/gitconfig_template" > "~/dotfiles/.gitconfig"; then
      success ".gitconfig has been setup";
    else
      fail ".gitconfig has not been setup";
    fi;
  fi;
}

git_config
```

**In the console**

```
$ ./dotfile.sh --setup git
[ ?? ] This may overwrite existing files in your computer. Are you sure? (y/n)
y
Applying 'git'
Setting up .gitconfig
[ .. ]  - What is your GitHub author name?
```

**Then I cannot see what I'm typing...**

At the bottom of `dotfile.sh`, I redirect any error that occurs during my function call to `/dev/null`. But I should normally see what I'm typing. If I remove `2> /dev/null` from this line `sub_${CMD} $ARG_NAME 2> /dev/null;`, it works!! But I don't understand why.

I need this line to prevent my script to echo an error in case my command doesn't exists. I only want my own message.

e.g.

```
$ ./dotfile --blahblah
./dotfiles: line 153: sub_blahblah: command not found
[FAIL] 'blahblah' is not a known command or has errors
```

I really don't understand why the input in my sub script is redirected to `/dev/null` as I mentioned only stderr to be redirected to `/dev/null`.

Thanks

Comment: `ARG_NAME=$@` is wrong, wrong, wrong. `for arg in "$@"; do`.

Comment: Extending chepner's comment: if you really need to store the arguments, use `arg_names=("$@")` and `for arg in "${arg_names[@]}"`. Also, you really should have explicit shebang lines to make the scripts run with bash rather than a generic shell (i.e. start each script with `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Actually I have the Shebang. I simply forgot to paste it here. Thanks for the tips. Is it just bad practice to add this useless line or it's wrong for another reason?

Comment: I'm talking about Args, not the shebang.

Comment: @eakl It sticks the arguments together without any unambiguous delimiter between them. If any arguments contain spaces (which is completely legal, even in filenames), they'll be mistaken for multiple filenames. Also, when you use the variable without double-quotes, in addition to being split on spaces (and tabs and linefeeds), any "words" that contain shell wildcards will be expanded to a list of matching filenames. This has led to some really bizarre bugs...

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `-e` option in your `read` statements?

I did a quick test in an interactive shell.  The following command does not echo characters :

```
read -e TEST 2>/dev/null
```

The following does echo the characters

```
read TEST 2>/dev/null
```